# Equivalence relation on not equal sets

Tags: equivalence-relations

Can we define an equivalence relation $R$  which is a subset of $A×B$ on $A$ and $B$, if $A$ is not equal to $B$?

My guess is no. Because $(x,x)$ will not be in $R$ where $x$ is an element of $A$ (i.e. not reflexive).

Or are equivalence relations only defined on a single set?

Comment: A subset of $A\times B$ is a single set

Comment: Yes. But in creating $A×B$, we use $A$ and $B$ which are not equal.

Comment: This relation is defined using two sets $A$ and $B$.